# How to get a Repository from an Entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have an Entity called `Game` with a related Repository called `GameRepository`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\GameRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Game {
    /**
     * @ORM\prePersist
     */
    public function setSlugValue() {
        $this->slug = $repo->createUniqueSlugForGame();
    }
}
```

In the prePersist method, I need to ensure that the Game's slug field is unique, which requires a database query. To do the query, I need access to the `EntityManager`. I can get the EntityManager from inside GameRepository. So: **how do I get the GameRespository from a Game?**

Comment: Why not use a seperate service for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't. Entities in Doctrine 2 are supposed to *not* know of the entity manager or the repository.

A typical solution to the case you present would be to add a method to the repository (or a service class) which is used to create (or called to store) new instances, and also produces a unique slug value.

Comment: Why did they choose to do it that way? It seems to make everything significantly harder and less DRY.

Comment: @JasonSwett Yeah the slug case is a bit annoying like that. In most other cases, there are way fewer bad sides to the separation, such as when testing things it's way easier when there are no tricky dependencies to configure.

Comment: A method in the repository to "to create new instances"... Really ? Repository aren't ment to only fetch data ?

Answer (score 66):

You actually **can** get the repository in your entity and only during a lifecycle callback. You are very close to it, all you have to do is to receive the `LifecycleEventArgs` parameter.

Also see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PrePersistEventArgs;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\GameRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Game {
    /**
     * @ORM\prePersist
     */
    public function setSlugValue( PrePersistEventArgs $event ) {
        $entityManager = $event->getEntityManager();
        $repository    = $entityManager->getRepository( get_class($this) );
        
        $this->slug = $repository->createUniqueSlugForGame();
    }
}
```

PS. I know this is an old question, but I answered it to help any future googlers.

Comment: I'm glad you did resurrect it - I was one of those future Googlers. I was actually already working within a lifecycle callback and persisting my object relied on creating or fetching a related object.

Comment: Working for me ( Symfony 2.4), I think this one would be the accepted answer !

Comment: Is this totally fine or bad practice ?

Comment: @TrtG In general, you want as little logic in your entities as possible. So I would move this to a separate event listener/subscriber. Check the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: @Maurice, thanks. But if I understand it right, this doc is for creating general listeners that trigger on each and every prepersist operation... So we'll have to check the type of current entity before going further. That would probably lead to some mega "switch" checking if multiple entities have prepersist operations... Would that really be a better implementation or am I missing something ?

Comment: @TrtG you can make one listener per entity of action. And begin your listener method with `if (!$entity instanceof SomeEntity::class){return;}` If you need to listen to the same event for another entity, you can just create another listener. I would give each listener one responsibility.

Answer (score 4):

you can inject the doctrine entity manager in your entity
(using JMSDiExtraBundle)
and have the repository like this:

```
/**
 * @InjectParams({
 *     "em" = @Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
 * })
 */
    public function setInitialStatus(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em) {


    $obj = $em->getRepository('AcmeSampleBundle:User')->functionInRepository();
    //...
}
```

see this :   http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/1.1/annotations

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the logic encapsulated without having to change the way you save the entity, instead of the simple prePersist lifecycle event you will need to look at using the more powerful Doctrine events which can get access to more than just the entity itself.

You should probably look at the [DoctrineSluggableBundle](https://github.com/samjarrett/DoctrineSluggableBundle) or [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html) bundles which might do just what you need.