# Symfony call repo function in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, foselasticabundle

I have elastic mapping and use indexable_callback and in this function I need call repo function when I inject Entity manager in `__construct` and run elastica population have error because I think not calling construct and have error Call to a member function `getRepository()`. How to call repo function in entity ?

this my config:

```
                talent:
                indexable_callback: 'isPublished'
                mappings:
                    id:
                       type: integer

    public function isPublished()
{
    $query = $?->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->createElasticDeveloper();
    $queryResult = $query->getQuery();
    $results = $queryResult->getResult();
    if ($results) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

                    persistence:
                      driver: orm
                      model: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer
                      provider:
                        query_builder_method: createElasticDeveloper
                      listener: ~
                      finder: ~
```

I try add LifecycleEventArgs and when flush have error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Proxies__CG__\Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Project::PreFlush() must be
>   an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreFlushEventArgs given, called in
>   /home/ivan/host/aog-code/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/ListenersInvoker.php
>   on line 102 and defined

I have

```
    /**
 * @ORM\PreFlush()
 */
public function PreFlush(LifecycleEventArgs $event){
    $entityManager = $event->getEntityManager();

        $event = new CodeEvents();
        $event
            ->setProject($this)

        $entityManager->persist($event);
        $entityManager->flush();

}
```

But when

```
        $manager->persist($developer);
        $manager->flush();
```

Comment: You can't and do not want to relate your repo to it's entities. The entities should be as thin as possible. Where do you want to call this `isPublished`? Let's assume this is in Twig, it is best to create a Twig extension that does this then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access repository methods for an entity in symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712889/how-to-access-repository-methods-for-an-entity-in-symfony2)

Comment: no, not duplicate, because I use isPublished in elastic listener and I need use repo function in entity

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457899/how-to-get-a-respository-from-an-entity . But even though the second answer has a solution, you should not access the repository or the entity manager from within you entity and I'm pretty sure there is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: update my question

Comment: Quotation and code added