# Symfony 5 : setting a property based on a parent property value

Tags: symfony, service, repository, entity

In Symfony 5, let's say we have 3 entities linked like this :

- `Foo` is an entity that have `Bar` as child. `Foo` as one property called `fooProperty`.
- `Bar` have `Foo` as parent, and `Baz` as child
- `Baz` have Bar as parent, of course. `Baz` have one property called `bazProperty`.

Let's say that the value of `bazProperty` is dependent of the value of the value of `fooProperty`. My first idea was to refer to `foo` entity inside the `baz` entity class :

```
function setBazProperty($value) {
    if ($this->getBar()->getFoo()->getFooProperty > 0) {
        $this->bazProperty = $value;
    } else {
        $this->bazProperty = 0;
    }
}
```

But this occur many sql queries, as Doctrine will ask first to get `Bar` entity, then `Foo` entity.

So I imagine to access to `Foo` entity through an unique query managed in a repository class.

But, because of [the separation of concern](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/separation_of_concerns.html), I wouldn't inject the repository in the `Baz` entity, but I would use a service instead.

So I've created a `BazService` with two arguments in the constructor :

```
public function __construct(Baz $baz, BazRepository $bazRepository)
{
    
    $this->baz = $baz;
    $this->bazRepository= $bazRepository;
    
}
```

In this service, I've also added a method fetching `Foo` entity :

```
public function getFoo()
{
    
    return $this->bazRepository->getFoo($this->baz);
    
}
```

And last, in a controller, now I would like to get `Foo` entity :

```
$bazService = new BazService($baz);
$foo = $bazService->getFoo();
```

Here are my questions :

1. I'm not able to initialize `bazService` in the controller. The constructor ask for 2 argmuments (the entity and the repository) and I would like only to provide the entity and to inject automatically the repository class.
   I've tried to add it in serices.yaml without success (probably because I didn't instantiate `bazService` in the constructor of my controller) :

   ```
   App\Service\BazService:
       arguments:
           $bazRepository: App\Repository\BazRepository
   ```

Is there any other solution ? How I can inject the entity class differently in the service class ?

2. Using a service when setting a property is too complex is the recommended solution ? Some article ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712889/how-to-access-repository-methods-for-an-entity-in-symfony2), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457899/how-to-get-a-respository-from-an-entity) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186970/symfony2-access-repository-functions-in-entity)) recommend to use a service when the method inside entity class become more complex and require external entity or repositories. But maybe there's a lighter solution...

Comment: very opinionated question ;o/

Comment: I agree that the question is a little bit specific, but I'm faced a real problem to update a property that is dependent of a parent property. I would like to use the most elegant solution to write a clean and comprehensive code.

Comment: as a side note: I find a "service" a bit smelly, if it needs an entity to be created. IMHO the syntax should be `$bazService->getFoo($baz)`. in your controller you could then just request a `BazService` via controller method signature and get it via dependency injection.

Comment: I agree with you. It doesn't seem very convenient to pass as argument the entity while using the service. I also try to create a class `bazService` that extends the entity `baz`. But this cause problem while persisting the entity and doesn't resolve the problem of separation of concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of concerns is IMHO the right argument to look at. There are some approaches to go for, that depend largely on how you retrieve the entity. However, in my opinion, the concern of an entity is NOT to fetch some other entities data from the database, it is the repository's or *maybe* the controller's concern. So let's see how to do that ...

One way is to automatically retrieve the parent entity / entities. Depending on your use case, you could do that in general (via `fetch="EAGER"` - see: [@ManyToOne](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone) / [@OneToOne](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetoone)), otherwise you could implement a special repository function, that fetches the additional entities. If your entities always only have at most one parent each, this can absolutely reduce the number of queries from 3 to 1, since the parent and parent of parent entities can be retrieved simultaneously.

```
// in BazRepository
public function getWithParents($id) {
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('baz');
   $qb->leftJoin('baz.bar', 'bar')
      ->addSelect('bar')
      ->leftJoin('bar.foo', 'foo')
      ->addSelect('foo')
      ->where('baz.id = :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id);
   return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

if the child entity accesses the parent entity, it should just use the entity from cache and avoid a second query (source: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/join-n-plus-one)

If having the entities is already "too much", you can slightly cheat by (again) creating a custom repository method that not only fetches the Baz entity, but also the Foo.fooProperty value and sets it for a virtual/temporary property on the Baz entity.

```
// in BazRepository
public function getWithFooProperty(int $id) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('baz');
    $qb->leftJoin('baz.bar', 'bar')
       ->lefTJoin('bar.foo', 'foo')
       ->select('foo.fooProperty as fooProperty')
       ->where('baz.id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id', $id);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); // should be an array with an array with two keys, but I might be wrong
    if(count($result) == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    $baz = $row[0][0];
    $baz->fooProperty = $row[0][1];

    return $baz;
}
```

(Disclaimer: please check the $result here, to see if the accesses are correct)

you now could access it in **Baz**:

```
function getFooProperty() {
    if(isset($this->fooProperty)) {
        return $this->fooProperty;
    } else {
        // fallback, in case entity was fetched by another repository method
        return $this->getBar()->getFoo()->getFooProperty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jakumi. So it mean I need to call first `getWithFooProperty` in my controller before setting `bazProperty` :

    `$baz = $bazRepository->getWithFooProperty($baz->getId());
      $baz->setBazProperty($value);`

Comment: @Mulot I assume you mean in a controller method? you can specify the repository-method used to fetch your Baz. have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression

Comment: Yes, of course, in a controller !
Thank you for your answer. So I must use `getWithFooProperty` first each time I would update `bazProperty`.

Comment: not must, but should, if you want to only have one select. you should always have the soft fallback, just in case you forget it at some point, don't want it to behave differently